# Subtitle inside slide (Beamer)

Tags: beamer

I want to divide a slide of my Beamer presentation in two parts: RQ's and contribution.  Is there a smarter way to do it in comparison with the MWE which I am attaching?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}                                      % Math equations, etc.
\mode<presentation> {
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,dcolumn}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs


\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{RQ's and contribution}

\textbf{Research questions}

\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua? 

\vspace{0.5cm
\hspace{-0.7cm}\textbf{Contribution}
}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, you seem to like  `graphicx` very much if you load it 3 times, but in fact you don't need it at all, as beamer already provides this functionality.

Comment: `booktabs` seems also to be one of your favourites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having to guess any manual spaces, I would do the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{bm}
\mode<presentation> {
    \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,dcolumn}
    \usetheme{Boadilla}
    \usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
    \renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{RQ's and contribution}

\textbf{Research questions}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua? 
    \end{itemize}
\bigskip
\textbf{Contribution}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: mathtools load amsmath ...